# Pass a dynamic parameter in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

I want to pass a dynamic parameter in Jenkins in a scheduled job (this build runs every day at 3:00 am)

This works if I executed it in my linux command line:

```
mvn package -DintegrationTag=$(date +%d-%m-%y)
```

or

```
mvn package -DintegrationTag="$(date +%d-%m-%y)"
```

or

```
mvn package -DintegrationTag="$(date +"%d-%m-%y")"
```

with these 3 options this is what is executed, for example (this is what I want to do in Jenkins):

```
mvn package -DintegrationTag=16-09-2013
```

but any of these sentences, do not work in my Jenkins goals and options (because the dynamic parameter).

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The solution**:

Content of the file which constains the script:

```
echo "NOW=`date +%d-%m-%y`"> env.properties
```

Path of the properties file:

```
env.properties
```

In project, goals and options:

```
clean test package -DintegrationTag=$NOW
```

Inject environment variables to the build process = true

Comment: You need to install the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) for this.

Answer (score 2):

In a Build "execute shell" section add this

```
NOW=`date +%d-%m-%y`
mvn package -DintegrationTag=$NOW
```

Comment: After executing this, the integrationTag param has not value in the generated jar into the app.properties.

Comment: Look at the console output and you should see that the command being executed is ``mvn package -DintegrationTag=16-09-2013``

Comment: You are right, but if the param (integrationTag) is not set in the app.properties I have the same problem.

Comment: The problem is not with jenkins, it is elsewhere in your mvn job

Comment: Maybe, but it does not work. And with the solution below yes. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be to execute a top level maven target in jenkins.
The first two steps of injecting the required variable value into the build environment remains same as the answer given by @Iker below.

In the third step, give goal as
    `clean test package`
and then in Properties section within the 'Advanced' tab, give
`integrationTag=$<your variable name>`

Note that this solution is useful when one creates a free style project in jenkins. For maven 2/3 projects,solution by @Iker is good:)