# Maven multi module jenkins project

Tags: java, xml, git, maven, jenkins

I've a multi-module maven application that we need build through Jenkins.
Project structure is like:

```
a.xml
<artifactId>parent-1</artifactId>
<modules>
    <module>lookup-1</module>
    <module>lookup-2</module>
</modules>

lookup-1.xml
<artifactId>lookup-1</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lookup</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<name>lookup-1</name>

lookup-2.xml
<artifactId>lookup-2</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.lookup</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<name>lookup-2</name>
```

now,
    mvn clean install -f a.xml works fine. For this I created one Jenkins job.
 Now, same as a.xml, I've another project with b.xml. b.xml has the same code as of a.xml except different Ids. So, I've created another jenkins job for b.xml.
Both jobs work fine. But, now I want to build both these project from single Jenkins job based on which project we commit in Git. For, this I want to have a new project(pom.xml) and where I want to put both a and b under modules tag. Like this:

```
pom.xml
<name>combined_project</name>
<artifactId>combined_project</artifactId>
<modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>b</module>
</modules>

a.xml
<artifactId>parent-1</artifactId>
<name>a</name>
<parent>
    <artifactId>combined_project</artifactId>
</parent>
<modules>
    <module>lookup-1</module>
    <module>lookup-2</module>
</modules>
```

But, its not working for me. I'm getting following exception in maven:

```
Child module D:\....\a of D:\....\pom.xml does not exist
```

Maven not able to find child module.
I've following project structure:

```
project
 |_ lookup-1
    |_ lookup-1.xml
 |_ lookup-2
    |_ lookup-2.xml
 |_ a.xml
 |_ b.xml
 |_ pom.xml
```

Any hint?

Comment: First why have you names your pom file different than `pom.xml` ? Furthermore can show the folder structure of your project?

Comment: we wanted to have meaningful name for our xml

Comment: I've added project structure

Comment: Name you pom file always pom.xml and nothing else cause this will cause mistaking...Apart from `pom.xml` is meaningful cause it mean `Project Object Model` which it is...and used by Maven so is you change the names accordingly to `pom.xml` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`a.xml` has 2 sub modules `lookup-1` and `lookup-2`. By default maven is looking for the sub modules in the nested maps. So you need to have the following directory structure:

```
<parent>
|
+- a/pom.xml
|  |
|  +- lookup-1/pom.xml
|  |
|  +- lookup-2/pom.xml
|
+- b/pom.xml
|
+- pom.xml
```

Alternative is to change the parent into

```
<name>combined_project</name>
<artifactId>combined_project</artifactId>
<modules>
    <module>a</module>
    <module>b</module>
    <module>lookup-1</module>
    <module>lookup-2</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven follows a project structure and each `<module>` will contain a `pom.xml` file. As you have explicitly stated the pom file in command line that file will be selected as the `pom.xml` for that project. However, for every submodule that is listed maven will search for the exact file named `"pom.xml"`  for each submodule.

From the folder structure provided, it can be inferred that a.xml can act as a pom file when explicitly specified in command-line but **it cannot act as a module** as it does not have a dedicated folder with pom.xml.

> A maven project in general has the following structure:
>
> - archetype-id(folder)
>
>   - pom.xml(packaging: pom)(with one module module-artifact-id)
>   - module-artifact-id(folder)
>
>     - pom.xml

If you are attempting to build only the module that has been updated then the module that is not checked in recently will not be part of the newly created archive. But if you still would want to do it for some "special" reason. The following method might be the one you are looking for:

**(I wouldn't recommend it -- as it is messy and goes against conventions)**
Have two sub-modules in a single project and also Have two .xml files (pom files to be specified in commandline). In one xml file lets say "a.xml" "module-1" is to be specified as a module and in "b.xml" "module-2" is to be specified as a module.

Using the currently modified module invoke the build on that pom file. Example, if module-1 is modified specify a.xml in the command line as the pom.xml.

Please note that I have not attempted it but if it is possible this is one of the ways I can think of by which we can accomplish what you are looking for.

*Reference for passing parameters :* [Pass a dynamic parameter in Jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830746/pass-a-dynamic-parameter-in-jenkins-build)

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities :

1. Either you need to fix the path of your submodules in the modules section of the parent pom.
2. While creating a jenkins job you will have to tell jenkins to clone submodules as well. when I started with jenkins, I faced similar problem. The solution was to enable "Recursively update submodules" checkbox under Advanced scm behaviors in Jenkins UI.

[image]

Comment: "sub-modules" in that part of Jenkins is referring to Git submodules. I think the question is about Maven submodules and all the submodules are in a single repo, whether its Git or some other SCM.